# SQL - Join from Lookup Table - Roll-up Output file into Single Row vs Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I have a lookup table with fields: Item_ID, Item_ID_Description

```
ID    ID_Description
501   Horse
601   Mango
701   Trumpet
801   House
901   Cola
```

I have a demographic table with fields: Name_ID, Name, Item_ID_1, Item_ID_2, Item_ID_3, Item_ID_4, Item_ID_5

```
Name_ID    Name        Item_ID_1    Item_ID_2    Item_ID_3    Item_ID_4    Item_ID_5
1001       John Smith  701          801          901          NULL         NULL
1002       Jane Smith  901          701          NULL         NULL         NULL
```

What I want the output file to look like:

```
Name_ID    Name        Item_ID_1    ID_Description Item_ID_2    ID_Description    Item_ID_3    ID_Description     Item_ID_4    Item_ID_5
1001       John Smith  701          Trumpet        801          House             601          Mango          NULL         NULL
1002       Jane Smith  901          Cola           501          Horse             NULL         NULL         NULL
```

How the output file is generated:

```
Name_ID    Name        Item_ID_1    ID_Description Item_ID_2    ID_Description    Item_ID_3    ID_Description     Item_ID_4    Item_ID_5
1001       John Smith  701          Trumpet        801          NA                601          NA  NULL         NULL
1001       John Smith  701          NA             801          House             601          NA NULL         NULL
1001       John Smith  701          NA             801          NA                601          Mango          NULL         NULL
1002       Jane Smith  901          Cola           501          NA                NULL         NULL         NULL
1002       Jane Smith  901          NA             501          Horse             NULL         NULL         NULL
```

Issue: instead of adding the description across each ID, in the same row, the output file is split out and is replicating the rows (3x, 2x). How do I keep the descriptions and IDs to one row vs multiple?

My Code:

```
select distinct
d.Name_ID,
d.Name,
d.item_id_1,
Case 
    when d.item_id_1 = l.id
    then l.Item_ID_Description 
    else 'N/A' end as 'ID Description 1',
d.item_id_2,
Case 
    when d.item_id_2 = l.id 
    then l.Item_ID_Description
    else 'N/A' end as 'ID Description 2',   
d.item_id_3,
Case 
    when d.item_id_3 = l.id
    then l.Item_ID_Description
    else 'N/A' end as 'ID Description 3',
d.item_id_4,
Case 
    when d.item_id_4 = l.id
    then l.Item_ID_Description
    else 'N/A' end as 'ID Description 4',
d.item_id_5,
Case 
    when d.item_id_5 = l.id
    then l.Item_ID_Description
    else 'N/A' end as 'ID Description 5'
from [demographic_table] d
left join [lookup_table] l
    on (d.item_id_1 = l.id or 
    d.item_id_2 = l.id or 
    d.item_id_3 = l.id or 
    d.item_id_4 = l.id or 
    d.item_id_5 = l.id)
group by 
d.Name_ID, 
d.Name, 
d.item_id_1, 
d.item_id_2, 
d.item_id_3, 
d.item_id_4, 
d.item_id_5,
l.id,
l.item_id_description
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your query

Comment: As mentioned by @LV98, please add what you have tried. In stack we solve specific problems, so adding the code that you have tried with an explanation of the errors or unexpected behaviour that your are finding, will help us to help you! Please refer to [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!!

Comment: Posting code now. @EnriqueBet, there are not any errors. The file generates, it's just replicating rows when I want all of the descriptions in the same row.

Comment: I have also tried adding l.id <> 'N/A' in the where clause and the output file does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Demographic TABLE(
    [Name_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Item_ID_1] [int] NULL,
    [Item_ID_2] [int] NULL,
    [Item_ID_3] [int] NULL,
    [Item_ID_4] [int] NULL,
    [Item_ID_5] [int] NULL
)

DECLARE @Lookup TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [ID_Description] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT @Demographic ([Name_ID], [Name], [Item_ID_1], [Item_ID_2], [Item_ID_3], [Item_ID_4], [Item_ID_5]) VALUES (1001, N'John Dough', 701, 801, 601, NULL, NULL)
INSERT @Demographic ([Name_ID], [Name], [Item_ID_1], [Item_ID_2], [Item_ID_3], [Item_ID_4], [Item_ID_5]) VALUES (1002, N'Jane Smith', 901, 501, NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT @Lookup ([ID], [ID_Description]) VALUES (501, N'Horse')
INSERT @Lookup ([ID], [ID_Description]) VALUES (601, N'Mango')
INSERT @Lookup ([ID], [ID_Description]) VALUES (701, N'Trumpet')
INSERT @Lookup ([ID], [ID_Description]) VALUES (801, N'House')
INSERT @Lookup ([ID], [ID_Description]) VALUES (901, N'Cola')

;with Itemz as (select ID,ID_Description FROM @Lookup)
Select d.Name,d.Name_ID,i1.id,i1.ID_Description,i2.id,i2.ID_Description,i3.id,i3.ID_Description,i4.id,i4.ID_Description,i5.id,i5.ID_Description from @Demographic d
left Join Itemz i1 on i1.id=d.Item_ID_1
left Join Itemz i2 on i2.id=d.Item_ID_2
left Join Itemz i3 on i3.id=d.Item_ID_3
left Join Itemz i4 on i4.id=d.Item_ID_4
left Join Itemz i5 on i5.id=d.Item_ID_5
```